# How to recover the IMEI from my phone with android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I use IMEI = telephonyManager.Imei, but it is still null even if I took the permision Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState

Comment: not supported by Android SDK (anymore), while each SIM slot has their own IMEI.

Comment: so how i can get my imei in xamarin ?

Answer (score 1):

[TelephonyManager.DeviceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager.DeviceId?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9):

Returns the unique device ID, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID or ESN for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not available.

I guess that telephonyManager.getDeviceId() is returned null with devices without sim card capabilities.

In this case I would check the API level and if it is bellow 26 than I would still use DeviceId otherwise GetMeid(int slotIndex).

```
 string GetIMEI()
    {
        Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            // TODO: Some phones has more than 1 SIM card or may not have a SIM card inserted at all
            return mTelephonyMgr.GetMeid(0);
        else

            return mTelephonyMgr.DeviceId;
    }
```

I use the code above, I can get IMEI number, and I don't have any issue.

Comment: actually there are 3 numbers to consider GetMeid(0), GetImei (0) and GetImei(1). I don't know what MEID is, what I need is Imei1 and Imei2 (if it has the 2nd slot also)